# Bootstrap 3 with Typeahead JSON remote

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-typeahead

I just migrated my backoffice from Boostrap 2 to Boostrap 3.

My typeahead instruction give me some problems.

On bootstrap v2 I had this :

```
var typeaheadSettings = {

    source: function (query, process) {

         list = [];

         return $.ajax({

            minLength: 3,
            item: 10,
            url: "/ajax/articles/",
            type: 'POST',
            data : { query: query },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {

            var resultList = result.aaData.map(function (item) {

               list[item.name + ' - ' + item.code + ' (' + item.category + ')'] = item.id;
               return item.name + ' - ' + item.code + ' (' + item.category + ')';

            });

            return process(resultList);

         }

         }); 
                },
                updater: function (item) {
                    $("#parent").val(list[item]);
                    $(this).attr("placeholder",item);
                }

        };
```

for now, with Bootstrap 3 and typeahead (v. 0.9.3) included explicitly, I am on this part :

```
     $(".typeahead").typeahead({

         name : 'resultArticle',
         remote : {

          url: '/ajax/articles?query=%QUERY',
          filter: function(data) {

              var resultList = data.aaData.map(function (item) {

              return item.name;

          });

          return process(resultList);

        }
     }

});
```

The call to the json is ok, but there is no return, I have no idea what I can do to debug/find solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Use web inspector/firebug/etc to look at the ajax response - is it returning data? If not, the problem is your ajax not bootstrap

Comment: I saw the ajax response, it's ok on this. So, How can I retrieve and use this ?

Comment: Is any other informations I can give in order to help me ? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first place you could consider to use https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead.

You should check if your `resultList` or the result of `process(resultList)` has the format of:

> The individual units that compose datasets are called datums. The
>   canonical form of a datum is an object with a value property and a
>   tokens property. value is the string that represents the underlying
>   value of the datum and tokens is a collection of single-word strings
>   that aid typeahead.js in matching datums with a given query.

To mimic your `/ajax/articles?query` i use:

```
<?php
class names
{
    var $name;

    function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }   
}   

$data=array();
$data['aaData'] = array();
foreach (array('kiki','dries','wolf') as $name)
{
    $data['aaData'][] = new names($name); 
}


echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

This endpoint always return a list of three names independent of the query. This list should show in the dropdown.

Your (adopted) js code:

```
     $(".typeahead").typeahead({

         name : 'resultArticle',
         remote : {

          url: 'search.php?query=%QUERY',
          filter: function(data) {

              var resultList = data.aaData.map(function (item) {
              return item.name;

          });
          console.log(resultList);
          return resultList;

        },

     }

});
```

When i run this `console.log(resultList);` gives `["kiki", "dries", "wolf"]`. An array of string which fit the data format.
The typeahead dropdown also show these name. (don't forget to include the CSS from: <strike>https://github.com/jharding/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css</strike>https://github.com/bassjobsen/typeahead.js-bootstrap-css)

Note you don't need your `return process(resultList);`

Comment: Thank you, I had very simple problem ... my json was not valid ! So I accept your answer cause that was my problem and you explained that well :)

Comment: https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead saved me loads of time. Thanks!